# Proof that $\{x\in\Bbb Z: a\mid x\}\subseteq\{x\in\Bbb Z: b\mid x\}$ if and only if $b\mid a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

the question is:

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $, $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}: a \mid x \}, B = \{ x \in\mathbb{Z}: b \mid x \}$. Then $A \subseteq B$ if and only if $ b \mid a $.

I know I have to prove both directions. This is how I prove it:

$\Longrightarrow$ Suppose $A \subseteq B$, then I need to show $ b \mid a $.
$ x \in A$ then $ x = an, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $A \subseteq B$, it means if $ x \in A$ then $ x \in B$. $ x = bm, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. since $x$ is also in $B$, $an$ can be written as $bm$. $an = bm$. $a = \frac{bm}{n}$. Since $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}, \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $ b \mid a $ is proved.

$\Longleftarrow$ Suppose $ b \mid a $, then I need to show $A \subseteq B$.
Since $ b \mid a $, $ a = bn, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. $ x \in A$, $x = am, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $ a = bn$, $x = bnm, n, m \in \mathbb{Z}, nm \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $x \in B$. Since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, $A \subseteq B$.

Could anyone correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that "Since $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}, \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$"?

Comment: In both halves of your proof, you start talking about $x$ without saying what it is.  You can't do that in a proof.  In the second half of your proof, you could change "$x \in A$" to "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$."  Since you're trying to prove $A \subseteq B$, that's a reasonable way to start.  Then the last sentence should say "Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $A$ and we proved $x \in B$, $A \subseteq B$."  But in the first half, you're _using_ $A \subseteq B$, not proving it.  You need to choose a value for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for $\implies$ is incorrect. For example, $1,2\in\Bbb Z$, but $\frac12\notin\Bbb Z$.

On the other hand, since $A\subseteq B$, it is enough to observe that $a\in A$, so $a\in B$. Therefore, by the definition of $B$, $b\mid a$.

The proof of the second implication is fine.